# Box test steps are causing an error in my Playwright test

Tags: typescript, testing, playwright

I have the following code

```
import { test, expect,Page } from '@playwright/test';

async function addAndViewCart(page: Page){
await page.getByRole('menuitem', { name: 'Women' }).hover();
await page.getByRole('menuitem', { name: 'Tops' }).hover();
await page.getByRole('menuitem', { name: 'Jackets' }).click();
await page.getByLabel('Items').getByText('Jackets').isVisible();
await page.locator('li').filter({ hasText: 'Olivia 1/4 Zip Light Jacket' }).getByLabel('M', { exact: true }).click();
await page.locator('li').filter({ hasText: 'Olivia 1/4 Zip Light Jacket' }).getByLabel('Purple').click();
await page.locator('li').filter({ hasText: 'Olivia 1/4 Zip Light Jacket' }).locator('button').click();}

test('testing', async ({ page }) => {

await page.goto("https://www.website.com/");

await expect(page).toHaveURL("https://www.website.com/");
await addAndViewCart(page);


});
```

What i did is define a function addAndViewCart for certain steps that later i can use in my test cases without having to write them every time.

The issue i am having is when i run the test i get an error "No test found". How can i avoid this ?